# Regarding Avg.Time Spent on Screen in Firebase Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Regarding Avg. time spent on screen. Below query is working. But result is not coming

```
select event_name, param1.value.string_value as firebase_previous_screen, 
param2.value.int_value as engagement_time_msec 
From `<table>',
UNNEST(event_params) as param1,
UNNEST(event_params) as param2 where event_name = 'user_engagement' 
and param1.key='firebase_previous_screen' and
param2.key='engagement_time_msec' 
group by 1, 2, 3 
order by engagement_time_msec desc
```

Pls. find attached the interface screenshot for your kind reference. Pls. help  [image]

Comment: let be honest here  - the query you provided  - has nothing to do with the question you ask - you should provide what you tried first so then we can help you with your specific issue that you are facing. so please apply some efforts first and then come back with real question - we are happy to help - but not to do your work from scratch :o)

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the code and most importantly data that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the your problem. You can also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Mikhail Sir, In Firebase analytics they are populating Avg. time on screen for screen Class. I don't know how to query the Avg. time spent Via bigquery

Comment: Mikhail Sir: Sorry for troubling you... I am unable to share screenshot in stackoverflow. Else i would have shared firebase analytics screenshot for better clarity. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Mikhail Sir: I pulled Unique Users from data studio for each screenviews. Pls.Help me to fetch Avg Time spent and unique screenviews datapoints from bigquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time Spent: The user_engagement event carries with it parameters that indicate how much user engagement time occurred on the previous screen.

engagement_time_msec: The amount of engagement time (in milliseconds)
firebase_screen_class, firebase_screen: The screen class and screen name, respectively, of the previous screen.

You can aggregate user engagement time per screen using this event.

In the near future, we plan to capture this engagement time in the screen_view event itself, so the advice at that point would slightly change to be more focused on the screen_view event instead of the user_engagement event.

Unique Screen Views/Users: These are based on screen_view event; i.e. the count of screen_view events is the count of screen views.  The count distinct user_pseudo_id that logged a screen_view is the unique count of users.